# Flask - ответ от сервера

Tags: flask

Идет запись файла в .h264, после остановки записи запускается скрипт который перемещает его в .mp4 контейнер.
Все это происходит с помощью FFmpeg и Flask. Если файл слишком большой и ответ не приходит в браузер, flask завершает работу текущего задания.
Как увеличить его время ответа, или заставить выполнять даже не получив ответа?

Comment: что используется в роли application окружения? ngixn/apach2? нужно в эту сторону копать.

Comment: @ВадимГорбачев только flask. Никаких apach2/nginx нету

Comment: ок. т.е. приложение запускается через app.run() ? а что пишет в лог? есть какие -либо ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем...

[man конфигов flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/) - здесь есть MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH.

попробуйте [увеличить](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/#improving-uploads) данный параметр до необходимого значения.

```
from flask import Flask, Request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```